# Can I display image in full screen mode with PIL?

Tags: python, windows, fullscreen, python-imaging-library

How to display image on full screen with Python Imaging Library?

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open ('colagem3.png');
img1.show ();
```

DISPLAY ON FULL SCREEN MODE!

Comment: Not with PIL. `show()` just opens a temporary .bmp image file with the default application associated with that extension. If you want to show the image full-screen, you'll need to manually use the `subprocess` module to spawn some image viewing application that accepts command-line arguments to tell it to display the image in full-screen mode. You'll likely also need to create your own temporary image file to pass to it as well. Note: There's no need to SHOUT in your questions—it doesn't make people understand any better.

Comment: I get it, but how i can do it? Just using "OpenCV" ? I'm sorry about shout...

Comment: Since you have PIL, you can use it to create the temporary file. Sorry I don't know much about OpenCV and whether it could be used as the viewing application or not. Windows comes with a `paint` and there's something called the "Windows Photo Viewer" (`photoviewer.dll`) which might be suitable if they support command-line arguments that would do what you want. There are other imaging view applications out there, some free, that you could also probably use (if they have the full-screen viewing feature and command-line arguments to invoke it).

Comment: On my Windows 7 computer the photo viewer's path is `C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll`, so  it looks like you could call it indirectly with the arguments `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" ImageView_Fullscreen "<image file path>"`.

Comment: I don't understand ... how "call it indirectly" ?

Comment: I meant via `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Core of the problem

`PIL` has no native way of opening an image in full screen.  And it makes sense that it can't.  What PIL does is it simply opens your file in the default `.bmp` file viewing program (commonly, Windows Photos on Windows [although this is Windows version dependent]).  In order for it to open that program in full screen, PIL would need to know what arguments to send the program.  There is no standard syntax for that.  Thus, it is impossible.

But, that doesn't mean that there isn't a solution to opening images in fullscreen.  By using a native library in Python, Tkinter, we can create our own window that displays in fullscreen which shows an image.

## Compatibility

In order to avoid being system reliant (calling .dll and .exe files directly).  This can be accomplished with Tkinter.  Tkinter is a display library.  This code will work perfectly on any computer that runs Python 2 or 3.

---

## Our function

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # the tkinter library changed it's name from Python 2 to 3.
    import Tkinter
    tkinter = Tkinter #I decided to use a library reference to avoid potential naming conflicts with people's programs.
else:
    import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def showPIL(pilImage):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    root.focus_set()    
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.quit()))
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.configure(background='black')
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
    if imgWidth > w or imgHeight > h:
        ratio = min(w/imgWidth, h/imgHeight)
        imgWidth = int(imgWidth*ratio)
        imgHeight = int(imgHeight*ratio)
        pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth,imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)
    root.mainloop()
```

## Usage

```
pilImage = Image.open("colagem3.png")
showPIL(pilImage)
```

## Output

It creates a fullscreen window with your image centered on a black canvas.  If need be, your image will be resized.  Here's a visual of it:

[image]

**Note: use escape to close fullscreen**

Comment: Great idea and portable, too.

Comment: Greaat job! but, I did some tests, some images are not resized and are centralized ...   example: if I push an image too large (1600x1600) it spends much of the screen ...

Comment: @SóstenesMelo  I just updated it.  It now supports image resizing, if need be.  And it centers the image properly.

Comment: @nfnneil thanks! It's working. but how to center the image on the screen?

Comment: @SóstenesMelo I updated it a couple minutes afterward to fix that.  Go ahead and retry it with the new one.  I changed the location to `w/2, h/2`.

Comment: God job!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great job, works on Ubuntu, but couldn't get it to work on a Mac (High Sierra 10.13.3). Appears in dock but nothing appears on screen.

Comment: @Aaron It'll be hard for me to debug that as I don't own a mac.  If you can get it working and send me a copy that'd be awesome.  However,  I did do a brief google search and there's something about updating ActiveTCL.

Comment: @Neil I need to ask. I am trying to make something like a screenshot app and I want it to be similar to Lightshot, because I think it looks good, so I want a screenshot of the whole screen displayed and then after clicking 2 points you get that part of the screen. Your solution worked and the screenshot was displayed in fullscreen, but I could get input from the mouse when it was open. Is there something to fix this?